# Efficient protocol decoder with C/C++ structs - dealing with bits

Tags: c, struct, protocols

Basically, I have the following protocol for satellite Whole Orbit Data (WOD)
[image: Whole Orbit Data format]

Each dataset is encoded as shown in the figure below
[image: Data Set format]

I have declared one struct for the data set

```
struct wod_raw {
unsigned  mode : 1;//One bit for mode
unsigned char vbat;
unsigned char ibat;
unsigned char i_3v3;
unsigned char i_5v;
unsigned char tcomm;
unsigned char teps;
unsigned char tbatt;
};
```

Since the WOD packet contains 32 datasets (of 57 bytes each) and time(epoch), I declared the WOD struct packet as follows

```
struct wod_packet {
unsigned int epoch;
wod_raw frames[32]; //32 datasets
};
```

I have a WOD packet saved in a file. Its size is 1856 bits(232 bytes) as shown in the format. After the packet is read from the file, it is assigned to a wod_packet packet as shown below

```
unsigned char* mystring;
mystring = read_from_file(filename, 232);
hexdump((char*)mystring,232); //Just to make sure data is ready properly
wod_packet* pkt = (wod_packet*)malloc(sizeof(wod_packet));
pkt = (wod_packet*)(mystring);
```

I accessed the epoch data without any problems

```
 printf("Unsigned epoch: %d\n",(int)pkt->epoch);
```

I accessed the array of 32 data sets and try to decode one of them

```
wod_raw* wod;
wod = (wod_raw*)malloc(sizeof(wod));
wod =  pkt->frames;
printf("Size of frames : %d \n",sizeof(pkt));
wod_raw test = wod[0];
decode_wod_raw(test);
```

Unfortunately, the values I read in my wod_raw structs are not correct. Turns out my problems arise due to the fact that the size of wod_raw structs is 64 bits instead of 57 as I specified (unsigned int mode : 1). I have been using structs to write my protocols things are not always complicated when dealing with a protocol where data is framed in full bytes are opposed to bits. The only other alternative I have is to manually extract all the mode bits and which will result into 56 bits per dataset (7 bytes) but I'm hoping there could be a more efficient way. Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++ - pick one language

Comment: The reason for that should be the padding and packing settings of your system. Specify the packing and padding and it should help you.

Comment: @Aeonos I did a bit of literature and tried to use #pragma pack(push,1) .... #pragma pack(pop)  without much success. Is this what you are referring to? An example or a link to any example would shed more light on the matter.

Comment: I have no good example at hand, but try to declare `mode` as `unsigned char mode : 1`. Omitting the datatype for unsigned most of the time results in `unsigned int`. And the more importend part, add the line `#pragma pack(2)` before your struct definition, which will allocate a multiple of 2 byte for each variable.This works for gcc compilers. you can also try `#pragma pack(1)` what sometimes seems not to work.

Comment: `#pragma pack` aligns bytes but you want to align bits. I do not know whether this is possible but I have a feeling it is not. I do not think that you can avoid some bit manipulation.